# Retorno de uma função JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funções

Quando executo o seguinte código os comandos que eram para ser retornados na real não são.

```js
var a = 0;

main = function(_this){
  console.log('Está entrando em Main');
  return function(){
    console.log("Retorno"); //Não escreve o retorno
    a++; //Não incrementa a variável
  };
}(this);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está faltando chamar a função `main()`. `main` é uma variável que é uma função que retorna outra função, sem executá-la não fará nada:

```js
var a = 0;
main = function(_this){
  console.log('Está entrando em Main');
  return function(){
    console.log("Retorno"); //Não escreve o retorno
    a++; //Não incrementa a variável
  };
}(this);
main();
console.log(a);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/CallFunction.js).

Comment: Caramba achei que com (this) já chamaria kkkkkkkk Pois quando faço o seguinte funciona apenas com o  Self-Invoking 
main = function(_this){ console.log('Assim vai apenas com a chamada abaixo'); }(this);

Comment: Nem precisa do `this`, mas só não está retornando uma função, está executando uma direto.

Answer (score 1):

Ou se você preferir, não precisa chamar o main() depois da criação da função. No javascript no tempos a oportunidade de criar Self Invoking Functions, que são funções que se auto executam automaticamente. Basta apenas chamar (), no final da função.

```
var a = 0;
main = function(_this){
  console.log('Está entrando em Main');
  return function(){
    console.log("Retorno"); //Não escreve o retorno
    a++; //Não incrementa a variável
  };
}(this)();
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Obrigado. Mas eu só queria entender pq tem que chamar duas vezes. Uma com o this como parâmetro (mesmo que não seja usado) e outra sem...

Comment: Se você não usar ele dentro da função então nem precisava passar como parâmetro, geralmente usamos esse tipo de abordagem para dar o bind no this global. Isso significar dizer que dentro da função você vai ter ao acesso a todo o this global de fora dela, o que for default da linguagem não acontece

Comment: Então o código que estou estudando faz justamento isto o bind, muito obrigado :)